# Select rows for which values are same in select columns Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to take the subset of my dataframe that has the same values for an arbitrary amount of columns.

Something like

```
df[df['col1'] == df['col2'] ==....]
```

But for an **arbitrary** amount of column names.

Comment: are you comparing columns from a single data frame or more than one?

Comment: @Jinglesting single dataframe

Comment: @sacul I want something that has this effect for a list of column names. I don't want to type them out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work

```
columns_to_compare = ["foo", "bar"]

def check_all_equal(iterator):
   return len(set(iterator)) <= 1

df[df[columns_to_compare].apply(lambda row: check_all_equal(row), axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @Jinglesting's solution:

```
df.T.apply(set).map(len) <= 1
```

Comment: Two heads are better than one as they say